# Dealing with a polynomial sum

Tags: polynomials, summation, rational-functions

I am trying to approximate the following function, 
$$f(x)=\frac{\sum^{N}_{c=1}\gamma_c x^{c+k-2}-\sum^{N}_{c=1}\beta_c x^{c-1}}{\sum^{N}_{c=1}\alpha_c
x^{c}}$$
where $\alpha_c$'s, $\beta_c$'s and $\gamma_c$'s are some positive constants. $k$ is a positive integer. I wonder if such function can be tamed and approximated?

Comment: Approximate where and in what metric? This is a rational function $f(x)=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N+k-2}a_i x^i}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}b_i x^i}=P(x)+\frac{Q(x)}{R(x)}$ where $deg(P(x))=k-2$, $deg(Q)<deg(R)$

Comment: I was thinking of something along the line with Padé approximant en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padé_approximant